# Getting data between two column name in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table that have column name like this-  cost_201410,cost_201411,...., cost_201506 etc.

Here firs 4 digit after 'cost_' means year and last 2 digit represents months.

I have to retrieve the data between two columns, i.e between cost_201412 to cost_201504.

But i can't figure out the query I need. 
Here is a sample - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2de80/3
Can you please help me?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
A sample using [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c2bd/3) will help a lot to understand your problem

Comment: this is payback for saving your data like this. zup with that?

Comment: You may want to just use a loop, running multiple queries.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean column *values* and not column *names*, or else you'd have hundreds of columns. If you mean column *values* try something like `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn BETWEEN 'cost_201412' AND 'cost_201504'`. If you mean column *names* then you have a serious design issue.

Comment: here i mean column names. Is it not possible to get all data between two column names ?

Comment: As I said. Please read how to ask. Show us some schema, some data and desire output. But as EdGibbs say looks like you have a very bad design.

Comment: here it is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2de80/3

Comment: Will the number of columns change? Add more rows to your sample, show us the required output.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for ?

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c7d7/11)

```
SELECT
  dateCost
FROM table1
WHERE dateCost between 'cost_201410' and 'cost_201506'
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c7d7/10)

```
SELECT
  dateCost
FROM table1
WHERE CONVERT(right(dateCost, 6), UNSIGNED INTEGER) between 201410 and 201506
```

Comment: Good answer, especially with the Fiddle. The only thing I'd point out is that the first query can be optimized nicely, whereas the second one can't.

Comment: @EdGibbs I think you mean is first query can use the `INDEX` on the table while second one doesnt?

Comment: Exactly, if the column has an index. Not a big deal: you had two great solutions and I just wanted to point out that the first is probably better than the second.

Comment: @EdGibbs I just want to point out what `optimized` mean, in case wasnt clear for the OP. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: here i mean column names. that means cost_201410,cost_201411 are col names. Is it not possible to get all data between two column names ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2de80/3